# Spark AnalysisException: Path does not exist: Azure Blob Storage

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to read data from Blob storage on Azure. I am using IntelliJ IDE. I have installed Azure plugin for IntelliJ. I am trying to read a file from blob storage but getting Path does not exist error. If I read same file from Jupyter notebook then it works without any issue. If I read a default file 'HVAC.csv' then I don't get error but if I add another file in same folder or any other container or any other folder then I get "Path does not exist" error.

Works: Default file provided by Azure

```
val rdd = spark.read.csv("wasb:///HdiSamples/HdiSamples/SensorSampleData/hvac/HVAC.csv")
```

Does not work: File added by me in same directory OR any other directory.

```
val rdd = spark.read.csv("wasb:///HdiSamples/HdiSamples/SensorSampleData/hvac/mapping.csv")
val rdd2 = spark.read.csv("wasb://container@account.blob.core.windows.net/Qafac.csv")
```

PS: I can see the data in Azure Explorer inside IntelliJ as well as from Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer. Can read it from Jupyter Notebook but issue with IntelliJ.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Set the below property in Azure portal for your blob container.

[image]